# How many one-to-one functions are there from a set of $4$ elements to a set of $8$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem:
Suppose that we have two finite sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ has $4$ elements in in and
$B$ has $8$ elements in it. How many one-to-one functions are there between $A$ and $B$?

Answer:

Let $c$ be the count we seek. The first element of $A$ can be mapped to one of $8$ places.
The second element of $A$ can be mapped to one of $7$ places, etc. Hence we have:
$$ c = 8(7)(6)(5) $$
$$ c = 1680 $$
Is my solution right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, assuming you mean from A to B

Comment: Yes. Since two different elements in $A$ cannot have the same image in $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. More generally, the number of injective functions from $A$ to $B$ where $|B|=m\geq n=|A|$ is

$$m(m-1)...(m-n+1)=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a $4$-element subset in a $8$-element set. Then choose an order on this subset. The total number is ${8\choose 4}\cdot 4!=1680 $. If $8,4$ are replaced by $m\ge n$, you will get ${m\choose n}\cdot n!$ choices.